# Correct way to use reactive method with if/else

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

This code works fine. It returns `Flux<Cars>` anyway. But I will to know is it correct because the if statement evaluates first, but publisher evaluates when the subscription will happen?

Should I use if/else statement at separate way from reactive flow?

```
class Example {
    Flux<Cars> getCars(CarTypeEnum carTypeEnum) {
        if (carTypeEnum == CarTypeEnum.VOLVO) {
            return carRepository.getVolvoCars();
        }
        
        return carRepository.getAllCars();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it is a personal preference about how you imagine your code to grow and be maintained.  If for example all of your other functions use if/else but this is the only one that doesnt, I would change it.  Otherwise it is your call.

Comment: @KevinCrum I am new in the reactive world. I have started learning it not so far. This is an example, and there are not other code

Comment: I think code is fine as it is, nothing happens in that code which should worry you. However, if you want to be extra safe, you can wrap your code with Flux.defer which will make it lazy.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Obviously within the context of a bigger project, something might be wrong, but as it stands there is nothing wrong.

Your method with the if statement is basically a factory method for a stream of Cars. Depending on the enum, it will return a stream of different types of cars. Only on subscription will the stream (provided by the repository) start to publish.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Timur your code it's ok, but that is imperative code with reactive programming we need to change the way we thinking.
Project reactor have a toolkit with many usefull operations.  should  test operators `.filter` and `.switchIfEmpty`

This code is the same using this instructions:

```java
    Flux<Cars> getCars(CarTypeEnum carTypeEnum) {
        return Flux.just(carTypeEnum).filter(type -> type == CarTypeEnum.VOLVO )
                .switchIfEmpty(other -> carRepository.getAllCars())
                .flatMap(volvo -> carRepository.getVolvoCars());
        }
```

Regards